# Show/Hide <span> tags

Tags: javascript

I want to hide  tags with a specific id or class using javascript. I have kept a single ID and CLASS for every span tag called "ch"(adding different ID and CLASS to each span is very difficult for me)
I have a checkbox which will toggle the visibility of the . 
Now here's the problem:
- I click the checkbox once, everything hides fine
- Click it the second time(to show the  again), all the content in the  tag goes to the left of the screen.
- Click it again and everything goes berserk
I want the code to show/hide the span tags when clicked and when the spans are hidden, I don't want that line to remain there. I want that entire line to be removed, and when it's set for visible again, I want these lines to reappear. I hope someone can help me. Below is the code:

```
function sh_chords() {

    tmp_log += "sh_c|";
    var b = document.getElementById("showing_chords").checked;
    for (i = 1; i <= lcnt; i++) {
        el = document.getElementById("ch");
        try {
            if (!b) {

                el.style.color = "black";
                el.style.cursor = "default";
                $(".ch").hide();

            } else {
                el.style.color = "#0000FF";
                el.style.cursor = "pointer"

                $(".ch").show();
            }
        } catch (d) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot reuse IDs.

Comment: two unrelated issues: in one place you use jquery but in another you use getElementById.  also, youve got a loop that does the exact same thing on every iteration

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jquery, you can use it's helper function which is specifically for toggling visibility.

```
$('.ch').toggle( $('#showing_chords').prop('checked') );
```